# Creating a list with values directly inside function parameters

Tags: c#

Instead of doing:

```
void MyFunction(List<float> list)
{
    // do something
}

List<float> myList = new List<float>();
myList.Add(3.0);
myList.Add(4.0);
MyFunction(myList);
```

Is there a way to do something like this instead?

```
MyFunction(new List<float>{3.0,4.0}());
```

Meaning I keep all the initalization directly inside the function parameters itself.

Comment: does not have to do with anonimous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. Remove the last pair of parentheses (and cast your doubles to floats):

```
MyFunction(new List<float> { 3.0f, 4.0f });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding information about the most cool `params` keyword. It allows you to do the following:

```
void MyFunction(params float[] list)
{
    // do something
}

MyFunction(new float[] { 3.0f, 4.0f }); // valid call
MyFunction(3.0f, 4.0f); // also valid
MyFunction(32f); // also valid
MyFunction(); // also valid, beware! list will be an empty array
MyFunction(null); // also valid, beware! list will be null
```

Note that doing this: `new float[] { 3.0f, 4.0f }` is what's called collection initializer. You can use that regardless to whether you send it as a parameter or not. The others are the benefits of the use of the keyword `params`, which really just makes it shorter and easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) or a [params array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

Your example was unable to compile because of a prohibited implicit cast with precision loss from double to float.

You need a number literal with less precision then the destination type, an exact type number literal, or an explicit cast.

The following example shows both the List and params array initialization in method parameters:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Original code with correct constant type.
        MyFunction(new List<float> { 3.0f, 4.0f });

        // Using an overload with a params array argument.
        MyFunction(3.0f, 4.0f);

        // Various float constant flavours.
        MyFunction(3f, 3.0f, .0f, 3e-10f, (float)3);

        // Implicit cast to float from anything with lesser precision or an explicit cast to float.
        MyFunction((byte)1, (short)1, (int)1, 1, (long)1, 1L, (float)1);
    }

    void MyFunction(List<float> list)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void MyFunction(params float[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```